# how to change java version of Azul Zulu on MacOS with apple silicon

Tags: java, azul-zulu

I have java 11 and java 8 installed, but cant find out how to change it.  11 is the default.  I need to downgrade to 8.

JAVA_HOME is not set, so I dont know how its picking up the 11 version.

```
% ls -1 /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/
zulu-11.jdk
zulu-8.jdk

/usr/libexec/java_home -V               
Matching Java Virtual Machines (2):
    11.0.10 (arm64) "Azul Systems, Inc." - "Zulu 11.45.27" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-11.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.8.0_362 (arm64) "Azul Systems, Inc." - "Zulu 8.68.0.21" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-8.jdk/Contents/Home
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-11.jdk/Contents/Home
     
java -version
openjdk version "11.0.10" 2021-01-19 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Zulu11.45+27-CA (build 11.0.10+9-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Zulu11.45+27-CA (build 11.0.10+9-LTS, mixed mode)
```

how do you change versions withAzul?  I'm using it as the oracle version doesn't support Arm directly.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a tool like [jEnv](https://www.jenv.be/) or [sdkman](https://sdkman.io/) that helps you install and manage different versions of Java.

jEnv in particular works only for Java, while sdkman allows multiple JDKs and SDKs.

Comment: Indeed, SDKMAN! works well on macOS for installing JDKs from your choice of multiple vendors.